# Why this equality is true ? (String constant poll / Heap)

Tags: java, string

I'm making some experiments about the ***string constants pool*** and ***interning*** in java
And I came across an example where I couldn't get it clear because I'm missing something.
Here is the simple code:

```
String s1 = new String("GFG");// here s1 should be created in the HEAP ('new' keyword)

String s2 = s1.concat("GFG"); // here s2 also should be created in the HEAP (runtime operation)

String s3 = s2.intern();      // here s3 has a reference form SCP 
    
System.out.println(s2 == s3); // true!
```

SO I did not understand how s2 reference variable became pointing to the string object in SCP exactly like s3.
Could someone point to what I'm missing here.

Comment: "*So the problem is that I cannot get why the result shows true even that s2 and s3 belong to 2 different memory areasv*" - No they don't. The references `s2` and `s3` reference one and the same object. Otherwise, `==` wouldn't return `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the docs for [`String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern--), you'll find that:

> When the intern method is invoked, if the pool already contains a string equal to this String object as determined by the equals(Object) method, then the string from the pool is returned. **Otherwise, this String object is added to the pool and a reference to this String object is returned.**

What `s2.intern()` does is add `s2` to the intern pool and return a reference to that object, which you call `s3`. Thus, they are the same object.

Comment: "What s2.intern() does is add s2 to the intern pool and return a reference to that object" so the created reference from the pool is returned to s3, how that change the reference of s2 that initially was pointing to the  string in Heap ?

Comment: The specifics related to the location of the SCP in memory are different depending on your JVM implementation. The *value* of the `s2` is **not** *copied* to the intern pool; the object is just added to it. When you `intern` a string not already present in the pool, it returns a reference pointing to the same original object.

Comment: The intern pool is basically a data structure containing references to strings. In earlier java versions (up to Java 6) some of these strings lived in a special area called "perm gen", but nothing prevents this intern pool from referencing strings that live in the heap. In more recent java versions (from Java 7 onward) all string objects are allocated on the heap anyway.